# WKWebview Photo Library error

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, wkwebview

I am creating hybrid app, which have WKWebview. This app read image from Photo library and camera.

When I select photo from Photo Library in iOS 11 its not upload, but If you choose Camera it works fine and photo get upload. I don't know whats wrong with photo library. I have given permission in "info.plist", still its not working.It gives following error.

> errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error
>   Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

I have read some places that it because of iOS 11 have bug, Do any one know is it true? Is there any alternative we can use till iOS 11 bug is resolve?